Azure MSAL broker signature hash question
I am working through updating an Android application at my place of business. I am working with Azure SSO and I'm able to get the SSO working with a signature hash generated from the app's signing key. However, the signing key uses an insecure password and I wanted to change it out for a stronger password. I went into the Google Play console and enrolled in Google managed signing. This means I now have an upload key and an app signing key. My question is, if I have the hash of the upload key in the configuration in Azure instead of the hash of the signing key, then will I have a problem logging in to the app once it's released? The Azure getting started tutorial recommends you use the debug keystore, but I don't know if that is what it should be in production. Can I put both in as valid redirect URIs and have it work in development and production?
